# How to dynamically disable the button of antd modal using button props

Tags: antd, react-typescript

I have an antd Modal, i am trying to validate a field and provided validation to it. How can i enable/disable the Ok button based on the validation. If the validation is successful then button should be enabled else disabled.

```
<Form>
    <Modal
      title={modalHeader}
      okText="ADD FIELD"
      cancelText="CANCEL"
      visible={visible}
      onCancel={onCancelHandler}
      onOk={() => onAddFieldHandler(fieldName)}
      width={600}
      okButtonProps={{disabled:true}}
    >
      <p>Please provide name</p>
      <Form.Item
      name="fieldName"
      rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please enter name' }]}
      >
      <FieldNameInput
        placeholder="Field name..."
        value={fieldName}
        onChange={(event) => setFieldName(event.target.value)}

      />
      </Form.Item>
    </Modal>
    </Form>
```

Comment: This code allows me to submit the form even if it has validation errors. How can i restrict submitting it.

Comment: Please accept and [vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) if your request is satisfied.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `onFieldsChange` from Antd [Forms API](https://ant.design/components/form/#Form) togehter with `geFieldsError` and the `okButtonProps` from [Antd Modal API](https://ant.design/components/modal/#API).

```
  const [form] = Form.useForm();
  const [buttonDisabled, setButtonDisabled] = useState(true);
  return (
    <Modal
      ...
      okButtonProps={{ disabled:  buttonDisabled  }}
    >
     <Form
        form={form}
        ...
        onFieldsChange={() =>
          setButtonDisabled(
            form.getFieldsError().some((field) => field.errors.length > 0)
          )
        }
      >
```

Here is a working [Stackblitz](https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-shape-zyyow?file=/index.js).

Comment: I have an additional question to this, suppose i am validating a field against special character validation, how can i catch which special character is causing the issue. For example if i need to display the message that "X character is invalid".

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had Form inside modal and there is onFieldChange prop when you can pass function to perform some operations due to changes on from so you can sth like that:

```
const SomeModal = ({ visible }) => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();
  const [buttonDisabled, setButtonDisabled] = useState(true);

  const handleOk = () => form.submit();

  const handleAfterClose = () => { 
    setButtonDisabled(true);
    form.resetFields();
  }

  const handleCancel = () => ...some action to hide modal;

  const handleFormFinish = (values) => {
    ... some logic here
  }

  return (
    <Modal
      title={"Some title..."}
      visible={visibile}
      onOk={handleOk}
      onCancel={handleCancel}
      afterClose={handleAfterClose}
      okButtonProps={{ disabled: buttonDisabled }}
    >
      <Form
        form={form}
        layout="vertical"
        name="acceptform"
        onFinish={handleFormFinish}
        initialValues={{
          ...initial values here
        }}
        onFieldsChange={() => {
          const actualFieldValues = form.getFieldsValue();
          const anyError = form.getFieldsError().some((field) => field.errors.length > 0);
          .. some logic if error etc..
          if (anyError) {
             setButtonDisabled(true);
          } 
          else {
             setButtonDisabled(false);
          }
      }}
    >
```

and of course there is need to have some validators on fields

```
<Form.Item
    label={"someLabel"}
    id="field"
    name="field"
    hasFeedback
    rules={[
    {
        type: "string",
        validator: async (rule, value) => inputFieldValidate(value, "custom message")
    },
  ]}
>
```

and validator looks alike:

```
const inputFieldValidate = async (value, message) => {
  if (someCondition)) {
    return Promise.reject(message);
  }
  return Promise.resolve();
};
```

here is some nice to know that validator isasync and to make it work without any warnings just handle promises

Answer (score 1):

Having the Form inside the Modal, a way to update modal button status would be just running [form instance's `validateFields`](https://ant.design/components/form/), but there are two things to take into account:

1. This function is a Promise, so the state must update after an `await` with the validation results.
2. I've experienced some looping issues when using `onFieldsChange` (maybe the validation triggers some kind of field update). Instead, `onValuesChange` has worked good enough for me.
3. Running the validation into a `setTimeout` callback seems to be mandatory. Doing it without the `setTimeout` returns a validation error even when all the fields are valid because of an `outOfDate: true`. It seems to be because of how the Antd Form update lifecycle works, and waiting until this process has ended (what we can easily achieve with the `setTimeout`) solves that problem.

A succesful validation returns the form values object, a failed one returns an `errorInfo` object with the errors list, the `outOfDate` status and the current form values. You can use the errors list in the latter to get the validation messages returned by Antd to display more descriptive and specific feedback.

In the end, my approach has this structure:

```js
const MyModal = ({onFinish, ...otherProps}) => {
  const [canSubmit, setCanSubmit] = useState(false);
  const [form] = Form.useForm();

  return (
    <Modal
      {...otherProps}
      okButtonProps={{
          disabled: !canSubmit
      }}
    >
      <MyFormComponent
        form={form}
        onFinish={onFinish}
        onValuesChange={() => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            form
              .validateFields()
              .then(() => {
                  /*
                  values:
                    {
                      username: 'username',
                      password: 'password',
                    }
                */
                setCanSubmit(true);
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                /*
                errorInfo:
                  {
                    values: {
                      username: 'username',
                      password: 'password',
                    },
                    errorFields: [
                      { name: ['password'], errors: ['Please input your Password!'] },
                    ],
                    outOfDate: false,
                  }
                */
                setCanSubmit(false);
              });
          });
        }}
      />
    </Modal>
  );
};
```